# JAVASCRIPT- How to prevent object from reflecting changes to its all references

Tags: javascript, object

This is the code:

```
var master = [];
var obj = {};

obj.name = "A";
master.push(obj);
console.log(master);

obj.name = "B";
master.push(obj);
console.log(master);
```

Following is the output on console:

The name property should be **A** at one place and **B** at another place

[image]

But both properties are displayed as **B** only.

How to avoid this overriding?

Comment: You have a reference, not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you wanted to do. First define a type, then instantiate 2 objects of it and at the end put them in an array and show the array with them and their value.

```js
obj = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var a = new obj("A");

var b = new obj("B");

var master = [a,b];

console.log(master);
```